# Problemas con Cursor T-SQL

Tags: sql, cursor, transact-sql

estoy intentando diseñar un procedimiento almacenado que la llamarlo me modifique el campo linia de todos los registros que cumplan una condicion.
El uso del cursor es por dos motivos, familiarizarme con ellos y porqué el procedimiento creo que así lo requerirá a medida vaya creciendo.
La condición del código que adjunto, la cumplen 5 registros, la finalidad es que el campo linia sea el mismo multiplicado por 10.
El campo descripcion lo actualiza bién, pero la línia no porqué dice que no permite un duplicado, pero por que intenta duplicarlo?
Alguien me puede orientar?
Muchas gracias:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE prova
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @Description AS nvarchar(400)
DECLARE @linia AS numeric
DECLARE @nLinia AS numeric

DECLARE Info CURSOR FOR SELECT linia,definicion FROM d_albven WHERE  TRIM(NUMERO)='1' AND TRIM(LETRA)='SC' FOR UPDATE
OPEN Info
FETCH  Info INTO @linia,@Description
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @nLinia = CONVERT(char,@linia*10) 
    PRINT @nLinia
    UPDATE d_albven set LINIA = @nLinia
    UPDATE d_albven set DEFINICION = 'Modificat'
    WHERE CURRENT OF Info
    FETCH Info INTO @linia,@Description 
END
CLOSE Info
DEALLOCATE Info
END
```

Comment: Probablemente el campo **linea** sea la clave primaria de la tabla **d_albven** y por definición una clave primaria no puede repetirse, de ahí el error.

Comment: Claro, de hecho lo es, pero no se ver en que momento duplico esta clave, ya que la intención es que el valor de cada registro sea el mismo valor de linia multiplicado por 10.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que te falta un `WHERE` en el `UPDATE`, ya que con el actual actualizas todos los registros.

Añado el `Where`

```
UPDATE d_albven set LINIA = @nLinia WHERE linea = @linia
```

El bloque del código del cursor queda así:

```
BEGIN
    SET @nLinia = CONVERT(char,@linia*10) 
    PRINT @nLinia
    UPDATE d_albven set LINIA = @nLinia WHERE linea = @linia
    UPDATE d_albven set DEFINICION = 'Modificat'
    WHERE CURRENT OF Info
FETCH Info INTO @linia,@Description 
END
```

Comment: Parece que ahora funciona perfectamente,muchísimas gracias, aunque ahora, a pesar de que realiza la actualización, me retorna el msg: Error en la comprobación de simultaneidad optimista. Se modificó la fila fuera de este cursor.Parece cosa del tipo de cursor que declaro.

Comment: Correcto, la colección de `linea` cambia. Deberías buscar otra opción, un `while`, una tabla temporal, u otro método

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás actualizando toda la tabla 2 veces por cada fila del cursor.

Lo interesante es que no se necesita usar un cursor para lo que estás haciendo y todo puede quedar en una simple instrucción.

```
UPDATE d_albven set 
    LINIA = LINIA * 10
    DEFINICION = 'Modificat';
```

Comment: Si, solucionado con un Where, muchas gracias. Ya se que no era necesario un cursor, solo quería familiarizarme con ellos.

Comment: Lo mejor es que no te familiarices con ellos. El buen código SQL muy rara vez los necesita.